# Kill Processes Automatically as Soon as it Start in Windows

Tags: windows, process, exe

I am using a software which automatically starts a processes called **"browser.exe"** in huge quantity. I want to kill all **"browser.exe"** processes **automatically**. Currently i have created a shortcut using below code to kill the **"browser.exe"** processes on click, but we have to do it manually.

```
taskkill.exe /F /IM browser.exe /T
```

Is there any way or code so that the processes **"browser.exe**" get automatically killed as soon as they start?

Comment: Compile an empty browser.exe and replace the current one?

Comment: Or change the permissions on browser.exe, or use group policy or the Windows Application Compatibility Toolkit to block it from running.

Answer (score 1):

A simple VB (or other) script should do the trick. For example:

```
set service = GetObject ("winmgmts:")
Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Do While 11>10
for each Process in Service.InstancesOf ("Win32_Process")
If Process.Name = "browser.exe" then
' Kill the process '
oShell.Run "taskkill /im browser.exe", , True
End If
next
' pause for 60 sec '
WScript.Sleep 60000
Loop
```

Then just have the script launch at startup and it will attempt to kill all browser.exe processes every 60 sec (or whatever interval you choose) if it is running.

This should require very little processor time, so as long as you loop on the scale of seconds (rather than milliseconds), this should have no noticeable effect on your system.

```
Though I've been wrong before. :)
```

Comment: Wow, so I totally missed that this was spawning the process "in huge quantities". I apologize for my relatively useless original answer. It's also possible that the ambiguity of many processes with the same name will result in it requiring several runs to eradicate them all. I apologize, since I am unable to test this just now. But you could get the process PID from Process and then kill it based on the pid.

Comment: @Rahul was this helpful at all?

Answer (score 0):

If this process writes anything to the Windows Eventlog, you can attach an action, which in your case is running that batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you take a look into this - https://www.raymond.cc/blog/monitor-processes-that-you-want-with-kiwi-application-monitor/

I facing the same problem with yours, and the "Bill2’s Process Manager" fantastically solved my problem with just few steps of configuration.